# I'm try to allocate um String matrix with malloc, but returns segmantation fault, whats happen?

Tags: c

I'm try to allocate an string matrix, but, in the last line mt code returns Segmentation Fault, how can i fix it?

```
char **allocate(char ***map, int lin, int col){
    int index = lin;

    map = (char*** ) malloc(sizeof(char) * lin);

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        map[i] = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * col);
    }

    return (char**) map;
}

void **fill(char ***map, int index){

    printf("index: %d\n", index);

    for(int i = 0; i <index; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < index; ++j){
          map[i][j] = "aaaaaaaaa";
          printf("%s ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}



int main(){
    char **map = NULL;
    map = allocate(map,5,5);
    printf("\n");
    fill(map,5);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect only to show the last line of my matrix.

Comment: Why do you pass `map` to the `allocate` function, but you don't use the value? You also have the wrong type. It expects `char ***`, but you pass `char **`. You should be getting type warnings about that.

Comment: You need to reread the chapter on pointers and `malloc` in your textbook or tutorial. You're really confused about how many `*` you need.

Comment: But, the first * is to allocate an vector, the ** is to allocate an matrix, the *** is to allocate my string value, this is wrong? @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like the following.

Note the "const" as a string is a "const char *" not a "char *".

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char ***allocate(int lin, int col){
    int index = lin;

    const char ***map = (const char*** ) malloc(sizeof(char**) * lin);

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        map[i] = (const char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * col);
    }

    return map;
}

void **fill(const char ***map, int index){

    printf("index: %d\n", index);

    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < index; ++j){
          map[i][j] = "aaaaaaaaa";
          printf("%s ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}



int main(){
    const char ***map = allocate(5,5);
    printf("\n");
    fill(map,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Calling malloc this many times and having such a high level of indirection
makes for very inefficient coding.

It is sufficient in this case to make a constant 5x5 array of const char *

```
int main() {
  const char *map[5][5];
  for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != 5; ++j) {
      map[i][j] = "I should write my own assignment.";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, in my homework i need to allocate an matrix for a .txt file, and this  is my salvation. Thank's